# Ubuntu : Firefox performance too bad for JS intensive websites

Tags: 14.04, firefox, performance

On my personal computer, I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed and Windows 10. I have noticed that performance of Firefox on my desktop is very horrible, all pages take 4-5 seconds more to load, and whenever I am trying to upload some files, where there are previews created(whatsapp web, postimage.org), or some media intensive websites, the delay goes to 8-9 seconds. This is happening only on Firefox, not in Chrome/Chromium. Any and all JS intensive websites are bad. Any suggestions for improvement.

System specs :

```
Mobo : Asus B350plus AM4.
Processor : Ryzen 1700 
Ram : 16gb DDr4 3200Mhz
Graphics card: Rx-480 8gb., drvier : 16.50 AMD provided.
Latest FF version.
```

This doesn't happen on Windows 10, just on Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: Check the network delay by inspecting. This will give you an idea of whether the delay is in js execution by the Mozilla or not.
Does the issue pop up in Mozilla developer version also?

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using? Does the same issue occur if you run Firefox in safe mode (close Firefox and run `firefox -safe-mode`) or with a completely new (temporary) profile (run `firefox -no-remote -P` to open the profile manager and use it to create a new profile)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster : I am using AMD's proprietary driver : 16.50. Trying other suggestions now.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : Done, its better now, delay down to 2-3 seconds, but still high for media pages, but it has no add-ons, mainly ABP, ghostery.

Comment: Obviously there are no add-ons in a new profile, but it’s a way to assess how much of the delay is caused by the browser itself.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : Thanks, still not good in media websites... where there are loads of images loaded, which is quite common now..

Answer (score 1):

Off the bat I must say there are many differences in browsers and may handle JS differently due to the fact that Firefox and Chome are entirely different builds by different company's they are not created equally.

With a fully updated OS and a fresh copy of Firefox there is little you can do if problem persist.

1. Fully update your system

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get diso-upgrade
   sudo update
   ```
2. Remove Firefox and reinstall it. - you will lose all data in browser
   if it is not backed-up.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge firefox
   ```

   Delete `.mozilla/firefox/` in your home directory, should it still be there.

   Delete `.macromedia/` and `.adobe` in your home directory, these can contain "Flash Cookies" stored by the browser

   ```
   sudo apt-get install firefox 
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Check internet speed in both firefox and chrome is it the same ?
4. Do what I do forget Firefox and just use chrome. JK

   you can not compare Firefox on windows to Firefox on  Linux they are built entirely different where there is an issue on a Linux box may not mean the same problem happens in windows. It is my experience that main stream programs and devices seam to work better on windows due to the fact that company's build products more torts windows systems first simply because they are more popular.

   If a fresh copy and full update doesn't work it must be an issue with the Linux version of Firefox and will hopefully get fixed with a future update from Mozilla.

Comment: I have tried with new profiles as well, no luck, this basically does that.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a profile . have you done all that is listed above ? also consider some sites work better using a specific browser since the developer of the site  optimized things better for one more then the other. like I said above not all browsers are created equal.

Comment: ...due to the fact that Firefox and Chome are builds off of IE... what does that mean? And what is diso upgrade?

Comment: Megan : What are you smoking these days, pass it over.. :D

Comment: IE is not the chassis nor the frame, your analogy is just plain wrong. Nothing is build on top of internet explorer.

Comment: Im sorry ? smoking ? Do you get what im saying ?? If your question is why does firefox have issues when chrome doesnt its either an issues of bandwidth or  firefox itself . if you do every thing to ensure that firefox is fully updated and your os is as well. You are making sure every thing is current and replacing any corrupt or miss configurements

Comment: sorry my mistake I work on windows and linux and im referring to a windows setup :/ never the less they are two separate beast witch is my point and will never work exactly the same due to there differences in build and my points in my answer stand to fresh install firefox and update system fully